Should “address“ be a synonym of “invoice-address”?
Many novice Bitcoin users misconstrue addresses as a permanent identifier like email addresses. However, Bitcoin addresses should rather be perceived to have the character of a unique invoice identifier. A few years ago, BIP 179 proposed “Bitcoin Invoice Address” as a new term for “address”. They suggest that Bitcoin and Address are optional, the former only necessary when the context of Bitcoin is not present, and the latter only meant as a transitional step.
I propose that we introduce the tag invoice-address and make address a synonym for it. Any questions tagged address would then be automatically tagged invoice-address instead.
This would help clarify the character of Bitcoin Invoice Addresses as a single-use artifact, perhaps help curb address reuse, and also dissuade misuse of the tag in the context of email addresses, physical addresses, or IP addresses.

I don't think Bitcoin SE should use its position to attempt to "right great wrongs" (similar to WP:RIGHTGREATWRONGS), and that includes trying to push a change in widely established terminology. At worst this could confuse people into thinking "address" and "invoice address" are two different things.
Address reuse is also not as big of a problem as it used to be. Most wallets used today generate a new address for each transaction and many will display a warning when attempting to view a previously generated address. According to Jameson Lopp's latest annual review most address reuse is probably due to deposit/withdrawal mechanisms on exchanges that encourage it, which aren't guaranteed to change even if the terminology changes.

I agree with this exactly. Using non-established terminology on a Q&A site is just going to make the answers confusing, and barely have any effect in changing people's behavior.

It worked for "fee market" ⇒ "blockspace market", tho ^^
